# angular ui-grid two grid, prepopulate certain values from grid1 into grid2 cells

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have 2 grids on 2 different view templates that share the same controller. I want to populate values of grid2 with the values filled by the user in grid1. How do I achieve that? Is there an example I could look at?

### View1 template:

```
 <div ui-grid="section1" 
        class="sectiongrid" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-resize-columns>
    </div>
     <button ng-click="addNewItem(section1)">Add Row</button>
```

### View2 template:

```
<div ui-grid="section2" 
        class="sectiongrid" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-resize-columns>
    </div>
```

Controller shared between 2 views:

```
$scope.section1 = { 
                enableCellEditOnFocus: true, 
                enableCellEdit:true, 
                enableSorting: false,
                columnDefs:[{
                        field:'Data'
                },
                {
                        field: 'Location'
                },
                {
                        field: 'Level',
                        editType: 'dropdown',
                        enableCellEdit:true,
                        editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
                        editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.levels,
                        editDropdownIdLabel: 'option',
                        editDropdownValueLabel: 'option'
                    }],
                    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
                         grid = gridApi.grid;
                  }

            };
```

How to populate section2 table values with values from section1?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) function.

```
angular.copy(source, [destination]);
```

Then you could set grid2 as a `source` and grid1 as a `destination`.